# Handlebars Loader with Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-handlebars-loader

I have been looking at examples of how to use the handlebars-loader with webpack but none seem to be working with webpack 4.

**Error**

`ERROR in ./src/templates/property-list-item.hbs
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'handlebarsLoader' of undefined
    at getLoaderConfig (/Users/Sam/Desktop/mettamware/Public/js/node_modules/handlebars-loader/index.js:24:37)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/Sam/Desktop/mettamware/Public/js/node_modules/handlebars-loader/index.js:32:15)
 @ ./src/property-list.js 5:0-58 40:23-31
 @ ./src/app.js`

---

**When I look in `node_modeules/handlerbars-loader/index.js`, the offending function is this**

```
function getLoaderConfig(loaderContext) {
  var query = loaderUtils.getOptions(loaderContext) || {};
  var configKey = query.config || 'handlebarsLoader';
  var config = loaderContext.options[configKey] || {};
  delete query.config;
  return assign({}, config, query);
}
```

---

**My webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.hbs$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "handlebars-loader",
          options: {
            helperDirs: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/helpers")
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  }
};
```

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it. I've been searching for hours for a solution and have tried lots to things but am not getting anywhere.

Comment: I used to think the striking new feature about webpack 4 would be that it is zero conf?

Comment: If my answer resolved your question, can you select the check mark to mark it as the answer for the question? Thank you.

Comment: @Clay Thank you for your help! I actually already found a solution just before I saw your answer but have only just had time to post my own answer. Hopefully both our answers will be helpful to others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Webpack 4 `loaderContext.options` has been replaced with `loaderContext.rootConfig`.

[This commit](https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader/commit/075ddcf14c0ca9162f33bb45f7accffc9e5aff1e) has already been made to the `handlebars-loader` package to make it compatible with Webpack 4 however this has not been released yet.

For the time being I have uninstalled `handlebars-loader` and am using [this fork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@icetee/handlebars-loader).

### The following steps have solved my problem:

**Run these two commands**.
    `npm uninstall handlebars-loader`
    `npm install @icetee/handlebars-loader`

**In `webpack.config.js`, replace**

```
loader: "handlebars-loader"
```

**with**

```
loader: "@icetee/handlebars-loader"
```

Answer (score 2):

Also in the midst of upgrading an old webpack 4...

Apparently, it used to be possible to set custom properties on the config.  That is there where it is looking for the `handlebarsLoader`.

It emits this error when you do set a `handleBarLoader` property on it.

> For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
>
> Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
>
> Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:

```
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           handlebarsLoader: ...
         }
       })
     ]
```

In my case, set it like this for now:

```
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         options: {
           handlebarsLoader: {}
         }
       })
     ]
```